# Taking over existing Domains (HostedZones) in CloudFormation

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I've been setting up CloudFormation templates for some new infrastructure for a project and I've made it to Route 53 Hosted Zones.

Now ideally I'd like to create a "core-domains" stack with all our hosted zones and base configuration. Thing is we already have these created manually using the AWS console (and they're used for test/live infrastructure), is there any way to supply the existing "HostedZoneId" as a property to the resource definition and essentially have it introspect what we already have and then apply the diff? (If I've done my job there shouldn't be a diff hopefully so should just be a no-op!).

I can't see a "HostedZoneId" property in the docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-route53-hostedzone.html

Any suggestions?

PS. I'm assuming this isn't possible and I'll have to recreate all the HostedZones under CloudFormation but I thought I'd check :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. It's fine to make other HostedZones, they're issued with new Nameservers, just use the "HostedZoneConfig: Comment" field to note down which hosted zone is which and then you can switch the nameservers over when you're ready!